# MouseRegion doesn't cover positioned element in stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I struggle to get a positioned object that I have in a stack to keep the mouse region that I have defined on an element that is bigger than the initial stacksize. The content gets shown, but it doesn't keep the mouse region. Meaning, even I'm still on top of the positioned object, it disappears when the mouse leaves the defined area.
I also can't switch the size of the element because that would cause my content to get shifted.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve that?
In HTML, this behaviour is standard. So it puzzles me that Flutter struggles so much with it.

[Here a code example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3a3f513babf848aed23c73fc354ccbe0)

```
MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (_) {
          isButtonHovered = true;
          setState(() {});
        },
        onExit: (_) async {
          isButtonHovered = false;
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          height: 100,
            child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 200,
              height: 100,
            ),
            isButtonHovered
                ? Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: 200,
                      height: 500,
                    ))
                : Container(),
          ],
        )));
```

Answer (score 1):

The mouse region is constrained within the 200 of the sized box.. You can also change the height of the sized box based on the mouse hover like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool isButtonHovered = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (_) {
          isButtonHovered = true;
          setState(() {});
        },
        onExit: (_) async {
          isButtonHovered = false;
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          height: isButtonHovered?500:100,//<---Here
            child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 200,
              height: 100,
            ),
            isButtonHovered
                ? Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: 200,
                      height: 500,
                    ))
                : Container(),
            
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

**Edit**

I think the layout you created is wrong. I created a working demo for you. Please check this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool isButtonHovered = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Column(children: [
        Text("Content"),
        MouseRegion(
            onEnter: (_) {
              isButtonHovered = true;
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Container(height: 200, width: 200, color: Colors.blue)),
        Text("Content"),
      ]),
      if (isButtonHovered)
        MouseRegion(
          onExit: (_) {
              isButtonHovered = false;
              setState(() {});
            },
          child: Container(height: 500, width: 200, color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5)))
    ]);
  }
}
```

The mouse region will not work outside a SizedBox with specific size even if we set the clip to none in a stack that's inside the sized box..

Comment: Ok sorry I should have specified that more. That is the problem I cant do that because it would shift my content it has to be this fixed size.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please? shift content you mean?

Comment: I added a gif basicaly if you resize the Sized box you ofcourse make the element larger and you move content that is above/below this element but i want the element to stay the same size and the hover element to overflow.

Comment: so basicaly is there a way to overcome the constraint of the sized box without resizing it the content can be shown outside the box so why not the hover functionality.

Comment: I also added a codeexample now if you change it to your anwer you see what i mean

Comment: Updated my answer with a working demo

Comment: Hm it kind of works but it is unpraktical to use in a real app you cant just put the whole content in a stack :D And the overlay starts now at the content. But i give you an upvote for the hard work

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure will get initially 500 height. And rather than using `onEnter` it is better to use `onHover`. Also, I think enabling the max container will be based on hover position.

```dart
Text('Content'),
SizedBox(
  width: 200,
  height: 500,
  child: MouseRegion(
    onEnter: (details) {},
    onHover: (event) {
      final dx = event.localPosition.dy;
      // enter position > max height - min blue Box
      if (dx > 500 - 100) {
        isButtonHovered = true;
        setState(() {});
      }
    },
    onExit: (details) async {
      isButtonHovered = false;
      setState(() {});
    },
    child: Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      children: [
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ),
        isButtonHovered
            ? Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.8),
                  width: 200,
                  height: 500,
                ))
            : Container(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
Text('Content'),
```

Comment: Well but now it takes up all this unneccesary space that doesn't make sense from a userexperience view

Comment: depends, but while it is stack it might be ok, else other element will jump